# How do I put a div higher than the parent div?

Tags: css, positioning

I want to make this "food" div look alike as in the picture. I made position relative for image and position absolute for this "food" div (in my example "destination"). Though, I can't center it and put higher than parent div.

[[1]:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVD6v.png) https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab1nj.png

```css
.grid div img{
    width: 100%;
    height:50%;
    position: relative;
}
.grid div div{
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
    
   
    border-radius: 0;
    
    position: absolute;
  
}
```

```html
  <div class="grid">
            <div> 
                <div class="mini">DESTINATIONS</div>
                <img src="Middle-East-Egypt-Pyramids1.png" alt="альтернативный текст">
                <h2>Top destinations to visit</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin efficitur lorem eu est suscipit aliquam. In lectus magna, sagittis in est sed, tempus fringilla neque.</p>
                <h4>READ MORE</h1>
            </div>
            <div>item-2</div>
            <div>item-3</div>
            <div>item-4</div>
            <div>item-5</div>
            <div>item-6</div>
            <div>item-7</div>
            <div>item-8</div>
            <div>item-9</div>
            <div>item-10</div>
        </div
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, then come back and edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Containing element:** `position: relative` should be declared on the containing (parent).
   element.
2. **Nested element:** This will allow the *absolutely* positioned nested (child) element
   to be positioned *relative to its containing element*.
3. **Horizontal center alignment:** To horizontally align the *absolutely* positioned element, declare
   `left` and `right` property values of `0` and a the *shorthand*
   `margin` property value of `auto`.
4. **Negate default full-width:** Remember to declare a `width`, or at least a `max-width`, on the
   *absolutely* positioned element so that it will not occupy the full horizontal width of its containing element (this is expected
   behaviour of *absolutely* positioned elements with `left` and
   `right` property values of `0`).
5. **Adjust vertical offset:** Declare a `top` property with a value that suits the specific
   requirement, e.g: `top: -20px`.
6. **Improve selectors:** Finally, be *more specific* with the selector, instead of `.grid div
   div`, use the available class as a selector as `.grid .mini` - the
   class will attribute more *specificity* and will allow for more
   reader-friendly and intuitive syntax structure.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
/* for the sake of demonstration */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative; /* required to position absolutely nested element relative to contianing element and not windowe */
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.grid div img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.grid .mini { /* be more specific with your selectors */
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;  /* required to align horizontally center */
  right: 0;  /* required to align horizontally center */
  top: -20px; /* adjust accordingly as per requirements */
  margin: auto;  /* required to align horizontally center */
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <div class="mini">DESTINATIONS</div>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300" alt="альтернативный текст">
    <h2>Top destinations to visit</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin efficitur lorem eu est suscipit aliquam. In lectus magna, sagittis in est sed, tempus fringilla neque.</p>
    <h4>READ MORE</h1>
  </div>
  <div>item-2</div>
  <div>item-3</div>
  <div>item-4</div>
  <div>item-5</div>
  <div>item-6</div>
  <div>item-7</div>
  <div>item-8</div>
  <div>item-9</div>
  <div>item-10</div>
  </div
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to set absolute div inside the relative div. Now add left/right positions to the food div. Setting a negative "top" will bring it outside the parent div, giving it the look you want.

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: -10px;
```